# How do I scroll a row of a table into view (element.scrollintoView) using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, scroll

I'm dynamically adding rows to a table using jQuery.
The `table` is inside a `div` which has `overflow:auto` thus causing a vertical scrollbar.

I now want to autoscroll my container `div` to the last row. What's the jQuery version of `tr.scrollintoView()`?

Comment: As per [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/68165/javascript-to-scroll-long-page-to-div), this is apparently a built-in DOM function supported in all major browsers.  Simply `element.scrollIntoView()` will work.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

```
var rowpos = $('#table tr:last').position();

$('#container').scrollTop(rowpos.top);
```

should do the trick!

Comment: I found a case in which this didn't work as expected, added as an answer below with slightly different source.

Comment: This won't work with datatable's new `fixed scrolling` functionality/plugin.

Answer (score 90):

This following works better if you need to scroll to an arbitrary item in the list (rather than always to the bottom):

```
function scrollIntoView(element, container) {
  var containerTop = $(container).scrollTop(); 
  var containerBottom = containerTop + $(container).height(); 
  var elemTop = element.offsetTop;
  var elemBottom = elemTop + $(element).height(); 
  if (elemTop < containerTop) {
    $(container).scrollTop(elemTop);
  } else if (elemBottom > containerBottom) {
    $(container).scrollTop(elemBottom - $(container).height());
  }
}
```

Comment: This, sir, is not just an answer, it's a solution. Thank you.

Comment: You can remove the container argument and replace it with var container = element.offsetParent;...

Comment: @Laurens: That only works if the scrollable element is the direct parent of the child object. A more robust solution would be to iterate up its ancestry until it finds an element where .css("overflow") returns "auto" or "scroll".

Comment: shouldn't your forth line be 
var elemTop = element.get(0).offsetTop ?
The code didn't work till I did that.

Comment: Also just discovered the Safari/Chrome scroll the container as well as the entire page as well. Anyone know of a way to stop that from happening?

Comment: Should line 3 of this function: var elemTop = element.offsetTop; be changed to var elemTop = $(element).offset().top; ?

Comment: While this solution almost works, it has serious problems.  One is the typo, but more serious is the fact it does not deal gracefully with items that have any height.  The better solution is the plugin from @Robert Koritnik

Answer (score 29):

### Plugin that scrolls (with animation) only when required

I've written a [jQuery plugin](http://erraticdev.blogspot.com/2011/02/jquery-scroll-into-view-plugin-with.html) that does exactly what it says on the tin (and also **exactly what you require**). The good thing is that it will only scroll container when element is actually off. Otherwise no scrolling will be performed.

It works as easy as this:

```
$("table tr:last").scrollintoview();
```

It automatically finds closest scrollable ancestor that has excess content and is showing scrollbars. So if there's another ancestor with `overflow:auto` but is not scrollable will be skipped. This way you don't need to provide scrollable element because sometimes you don't even know which one is scrollable (I'm using this plugin in my Sharepoint site where content/master is developer independent so it's beyond my control - HTML may change when site is operational so can scrollable containers).

Comment: This one really does work.  Tried to fix the one from @Abhijit Rao to work, but it has lots of problems.  This one just works.

Comment: @Mark0978: But be advised that I have to update it to work correctly with jQuery 1.8+ Custom selector definition has to be done differently with 1.8+.

Comment: Got the plugin from GitHub and works smoothly as promised. Great job!

Comment: four year since update and this plugin still works like a charm. I used it in a angular directive :)

Comment: Four years later the plugin does not work for me--sometimes misses the mark with target almost but not in view.  Today, assuming target is just one element, I use javascript:       `var target = $(selector); target.get(0).scrollIntoView();`

Comment: Best solution! Clear, easy and elegant.

Answer (score 20):

much simpler:

```
$("selector for element").get(0).scrollIntoView();
```

if more than one item returns in the selector, the get(0) will get only the first item.

Comment: this would affect the scrolling of the page as well. So it wouldn't work.

Comment: This doesn't do animation, nor does it deal with scrolling inside a scrollable div.

Comment: This doesn't do animation, but I find animated solutions failing in my particular use case which has an incredibly long element.  The animated solutions sometimes miss the mark by a small offset.  @Mark0978 my use case is a scrollable div--not sure why it works in my case but not yours

Answer (score 6):

This runnable example shows how to use scrollIntoView() which is supported in all modern browsers:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.scrollIntoView#Browser_Compatibility

The example below uses jQuery to select the element with `#yourid`.

```js
$( "#yourid" )[0].scrollIntoView();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>..</p>
<p>..</p>
<p>..</p>
<p>..</p>
<p>..</p>
<p>..</p>
<p>..</p>
<p>..</p>
<p>..</p>
<p>..</p>
<p>..</p>
<p>..</p>
<p>..</p>
<p>..</p>
<p>..</p>
<p>..</p>
<p>..</p>
<p id="yourid">Hello world.</p>
<p>..</p>
<p>..</p>
<p>..</p>
<p>..</p>
```

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to scroll, you could use jQuery's scrollTop method. http://docs.jquery.com/CSS/scrollTop

`var table = jQuery( 'table' );
table.scrollTop( table.find( 'tr:last' ).scrollTop() );`

Something like that maybe?

Answer (score 3):

```
var elem=jQuery(this);
elem[0].scrollIntoView(true);
```

Comment: Wouldn't `this.scrollIntoView(true)` be much more straightforward?

Comment: answer as given is the only thing that worked for me

Answer (score 2):

I found a case (overflow div > table > tr > td) in which scrolling to the relative position of the tr does not work. Instead, I had to scroll the overflow container (div) using scrollTop to `<tr>.offset().top - <table>.offset().top`. Eg:

```js
$('#container').scrollTop( $('#tr').offset().top - $('#td').offset().top )
```

Answer (score 2):

Same from above with little modification

```js
function focusMe() {
       var rowpos = $('#FocusME').position();
        rowpos.top = rowpos.top - 30;
        $('#container').scrollTop(rowpos.top);
    }
```

```html
<html>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-cCueBR6CsyA4/9szpPfrX3s49M9vUU5BgtiJj06wt/s=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<body>
    <input type="button" onclick="focusMe()" value="focus">
    <div id="container" style="max-height:200px;overflow:scroll;">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>2</td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>3</td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>4</td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>5</td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>6</td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>7</td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>8</td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>9</td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="FocusME">
                <td>10</td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>11</td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>12</td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>13</td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>14</td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>15</td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>16</td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>17</td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>18</td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>19</td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>20</td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$( "#yourid" )[0].scrollIntoView();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>..</p>
<p>..</p>
<p>..</p>
<p>..</p>
<p>..</p>
<p>..</p>
<p>..</p>
<p>..</p>
<p>..</p>
<p>..</p>
<p>..</p>
<p>..</p>
<p>..</p>
<p>..</p>
<p>..</p>
<p>..</p>
<p>..</p>
<p id="yourid">Hello world.</p>
<p>..</p>
<p>..</p>
<p>..</p>
<p>..</p>
```

Comment: Scrolls the whole page and is literally a copy of the answer from @BarryStaes

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't add a comment to Abhijit Rao's answer above, so I am submitting this as an additional answer.

I needed to have the table column scroll into view on a wide table, so I added the scroll left features into the function. As someone mentioned, it jumps when it scrolls, but it worked for my purposes.

```
function scrollIntoView(element, container) {
  var containerTop = $(container).scrollTop();
  var containerLeft = $(container).scrollLeft();
  var containerBottom = containerTop + $(container).height();
  var containerRight = containerLeft + $(container).width();

  var elemTop = element.offsetTop;
  var elemLeft = element.offsetLeft;
  var elemBottom = elemTop + $(element).height();
  var elemRight = elemLeft + $(element).width();

  if (elemTop < containerTop) {
    $(container).scrollTop(elemTop);
  } else if (elemBottom > containerBottom) {
    $(container).scrollTop(elemBottom - $(container).height());
  }

  if(elemLeft < containerLeft) {
    $(container).scrollLeft(elemLeft);
  } else if(elemRight > containerRight) {
    $(container).scrollLeft(elemRight - $(container).width());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my stab at it and it's my working solution for my project.

```
function scrollToView($elem) {
  var $parent = $elem.parent();
  $parent.scrollTop(0);// reset parent scroll to calculate element's current position
  var viewH = $parent.height()-$elem.height();// calculate viewing pane height
  var elemTop = $elem.position().top;
  var viewMultiplier = Math.floor( elemTop / viewH); // calculate view multiplier
  $parent.scrollTop(viewMultiplier * viewH);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

here is an example of scrolling to the row you want

```
function scrollToPositionTableRow(container, elementFirst, elementYouWantScroll) {
  var rowpos = $(elementYouWantScroll).position();
  var tableHeader = $($(elementFirst)).outerHeight();
  $(container).scrollTop(rowpos.top - tableHeader);
}
```