# When jQuery accordion is clicked, needs to go to top of page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an accordion layout in jQuery with one section that has become rather large.  I need to be able to click the different sections and have the accordion open and the scroll bar on the right be all the way to the top of the right of the page.  I tried the  but that doesn't work and breaks the accordion.  How can I click a link and have the accordion stay at the top of the page?

code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>


  <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery-ui.css" type="text/css"/>
  <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="demo/dialog.css" media="screen" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="fixed-box/fixed-box/style-accordion.css" media="screen"/>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() 
{  
$('#other').change(function()
{ 
 $('#otherrace').parent().toggle(this.checked).focus();
 });
 $("#toggleElement").change(function() { 
    $('input[name=living]').not(this).attr('disabled', this.checked); 
  }); 
  $("#toggleInsurance").change(function() { 
    $('input[name=insurance]').not(this).attr('disabled', this.checked); 
  }); 
$("#toggleInsurance").change(function() { 
    $('input[name=insurance]').not(this).attr('disabled', this.checked); 
  }); 
$("#accordion").accordion();
$('[name*="race"]').click(function() {  $('#otherrace').css('visibility', $('#other').attr('checked') ? 'visible':'hidden'); });});$(document).ready(function() {
 $('[name*="RadioGroup1"]').click(function() {
  $('#RadioGroup1_11').css('visibility', $('#RadioGroup1_10').attr('checked') ? 'visible':'hidden');

 });


});


</script>
</head>

<body style="font-size:75%" >
<div id="centerColumn">
<div id="accordion">
 <h6><i can't post one than one link>Demographcis</a></h6>
 <div>
   <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="1">
     <tr>
       <th width="18%" scope="row">Last Name</th>
       <td width="31%"><form name="form1" method="post" action="">

           <input type="text" name="textfield" id="textfield" maxlength="20">

          </form></td>
       <td width="4%">&nbsp;</td>
       <td width="47%">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
     <tr>
       <th scope="row">Middle Initial</th>
       <td><form name="form2" method="post" action="">

           <input type="text" size="3" maxlength="1" name="textfield2" id="textfield2">

          </form></td>
       <td>&nbsp;</td>
       <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
     <tr>
       <th scope="row">First Name</th>
       <td><form name="form3" method="post" action="">

           <input type="text" name="textfield4" id="textfield4" maxlength="20">
       </form></td>
       <td>&nbsp;</td>
       <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
     <tr>
       <th scope="row">Address</th>
       <td><form name="form4" method="post" action="">

           <input type="text" size="35" name="textfield5" id="textfield5" maxlength="35">

          </form></td>
       <td>&nbsp;</td>
       <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
     <tr>
       <th scope="row">Rural Route#</th>
       <td><form name="form5" method="post" action="">

           <input type="text" name="textfield6" id="textfield6" maxlength="8">

          </form></td>
       <td>&nbsp;</td>
       <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
     <tr>
       <th scope="row">City</th>
       <td><form name="form6" method="post" action="">

           <input type="text" name="textfield7" id="textfield7" maxlength="20">

          </form></td>
       <td>State</td>
       <td><form name="form7" method="post"  action="">

           <input type="text" size="2"  maxlength="3" name="textfield8" id="textfield8">

          ZIP 

            <input type="text" maxlength="5" size="6" name="textfield9" id="textfield9">

          </form></td>
        </tr>
     <tr>
       <th scope="row">DOB</th>
       <td><form name="form8" method="post" action="">

           <input type="text" size="11" maxlength="10" name="textfield10" id="textfield10">

          </form></td>
       <td>&nbsp;</td>
       <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
     <tr>
       <th scope="row">Phone</th>
       <td><form name="form9" method="post" action="" >

           <input type="text" size="12" maxlength="13" name="textfield11" id="textfield11">

          </form></td>
       <td>&nbsp;</td>
       <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
     <tr>
       <th scope="row">Gender</th>
       <td><form name="form10" method="post" action="">
         <p>

             <input type="radio" name="Gender" value="female" id="Gender_0">
             Female 
           <br>

             <input type="radio" name="Gender" value="male" id="Gender_1">
             Male 
           <br>
           </p>
          </form></td>
       <td>&nbsp;</td>
       <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
     <tr>
       <th scope="row">Race/Ethnicity</th>
       <td>
         <p>

             <input type="checkbox" name="race_" value="asian" id="race_0">
             Asian 
           <br>

             <input type="checkbox" name="race_" value="white" id="race_1">
             White 
           <br>

             <input type="checkbox" name="race_" value="black" id="race_2">
             Black 
           <br>

             <input type="checkbox" name="race_" value="latino" id="race_3">
             Latino 
           <br>

             <input type="checkbox" name="race_" value="island" id="race_4">
             Pacific Islander 
           <br>
           <input type="checkbox" name="race_"  id="other"value="other" />Other, specify<br />
<div style="display:none" id="race"><input type="text" name="fname" size="25" maxlength="25" id="otherrace" /></div>
           <br>
            </p>
         <input type="text" style="display:none;"  name="race_" value="other1" id="otherrace">
           </td>
       <td>&nbsp;</td>
       <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
     <tr>
       <th scope="row">Living Arragenments</th>
       <td><form name="form11" method="post" action="">
         <p>With whom do you live? Choose all that apply<br/>

             <input type="checkbox" name="living" value="alone" id="living">
             Live alone 
           <br>

             <input type="checkbox" name="living" value="husband" id="living">
             Husband 
           <br>

             <input type="checkbox" name="living" value="partner" id="living">
             Partner 
           <br>

             <input type="checkbox" name="living" value="children" id="living">
             Children 
           <br>

             <input type="checkbox" name="living" value="parents" id="living">
             Parents 
           <br>

             <input type="checkbox" name="living" value="other_relatives" id="living">
             Other relatives 
           <br>

             <input type="checkbox" name="living" value="religion" id="living">
             Religious order 
           <br>

             <input type="checkbox" name="living" value="no_answer" 
                id="toggleElement">
             Choose not to answer 
           <br>
           </p>
          </form></td>
       <td>&nbsp;</td>
       <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
     <tr>
       <th scope="row">Education</th>
       <td>Highest level of education:<br/>
         <form name="form12" method="post" action="">
           <p>
             <label>
               <input type="radio" name="RadioGroup1" value="less_high" id="RadioGroup1_0">
               Less than high school</label>
             <br>
             <label>
               <input type="radio" name="RadioGroup1" value="some_high" id="RadioGroup1_1">
               Some high school</label>
             <br>
             <label>
               <input type="radio" name="RadioGroup1" value="high" id="RadioGroup1_2">
               High school diploma</label>
             <br>
             <label>
               <input type="radio" name="RadioGroup1" value="ged" id="RadioGroup1_3">
               GED</label>
             <br>
             <label>
               <input type="radio" name="RadioGroup1" value="some_college" id="RadioGroup1_4">
               Some college</label>
             <br>
             <label>
               <input type="radio" name="RadioGroup1" value="votech" id="RadioGroup1_5">
               Vocational or technical</label>
             <br>
             <label>
               <input type="radio" name="RadioGroup1" value="associates" id="RadioGroup1_6">
               Associates degree</label>
             <br>
             <label>
               <input type="radio" name="RadioGroup1" value="bachelor" id="RadioGroup1_7">
               Bachelor's degree</label>
             <br>
             <label>
               <input type="radio" name="RadioGroup1" value="postgrad" id="RadioGroup1_8">
               Post graduate training</label>
             <br>
             <label>
               <input type="radio" name="RadioGroup1" value="no_answer_school" id="RadioGroup1_9">
               Choose not to answer</label>
             <br>
             <label>
               <input type="radio" name="RadioGroup1" value="other_ed" 
                  id="RadioGroup1_10">
               Other<br/></label>
                 <div id="RadioGroup1_9"> <input style="visibility:hidden" type="text" name="fname" size="25" maxlength="25" id="RadioGroup1_11" /></div>
             <br>
              </p>
          </form></td>
       <td>&nbsp;</td>
       <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
     <tr>
       <th scope="row">Insurance</th>
       <td>Choose your insurance-check all that apply<br>
         <form name="form13" method="post" action="">
           <p>
             <label>
               <input type="checkbox" name="insurance" value="privateins" id="insurance_0">
               Private/HMO/PPO</label>
             <br>
             <label>
               <input type="checkbox" name="insurance" value="medicaid" id="insurance_1">
               Medicaid</label>
             <br>
             <label>
               <input type="checkbox" name="insurance" value="medicare" id="insurance_2">
               Medicare</label>
             <br>
             <label>
               <input type="checkbox" name="insurance" value="va" id="insurance_3">
               VA/Tricare</label>
             <br>
             <label>
               <input type="checkbox" name="insurance" value="noins" id="insurance_4">
               No insurance</label>
             <br>
             <label>
               <input type="checkbox" name="insurance" value="noknowins" id="toggleInsurance">
             </label>
             <label>Choose not to answer</label>
             <br>
             <label>
               <input type="checkbox" name="insurance" value="no_ans_ins" id="insurance_6">
             </label>
             Do not know<br>
              </p>
          </form></td>
       <td>&nbsp;</td>
       <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
     <tr>
       <th scope="row">Income</th>
       <td>Gross income of your household<br>
         <form name="form14" method="post" action="">
           <p>
             <label>
               <input type="radio" name="income" value="tenk" id="income_0">
               Less than $10,000</label>
             <br>
             <label>
               <input type="radio" name="income" value="fifteenk" id="income_1">
               Less than $15,000</label>
             <br>
             <label>
               <input type="radio" name="income" value="twentyk" id="income_2">
               Less than $20,000</label>
             <br>
             <label>
               <input type="radio" name="income" value="twentyfivek" id="income_3">
               Less than $25,000</label>
             <br>
             <label>
               <input type="radio" name="income" value="thirtyfivek" id="income_4">
               Less than $35,000</label>
             <br>
             <label>
               <input type="radio" name="income" value="fiftyk" id="income_5">
               Less than $50,000</label>
             <br>
             <label>
               <input type="radio" name="income" value="seventyfivek" id="income_6">
               Less than $75,000</label>
             <br>
             <label>
               <input type="radio" name="income" value="dontknow" id="income_7">
               I don't know</label>
             <br>
             <label>
               <input type="radio" name="income" value="no_answer_income" id="income_8">
               Choose not to answer</label>
             <br>
              </p>
          </form></td>
       <td>&nbsp;</td>
       <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
      </table>

 </div>
 <h3><i can't post one than one link>Injury Information</a></h3>

    <div>
  <p>
  blahlbalh
  </p>
 </div>

</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Any chance you can post this on a page?  It's a bit to digest.

Comment: i'm not sure what you mean, exactly.

Comment: i suppose i could remove the JS functions that i have in there and remove the content itself.  would that be helpful?

Comment: PS: You have two document.ready.

Comment: there's two $(document).ready?  what is the purpose for that?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
object.scrollIntoView(); // moves the viewport
```

or

```
window.scrollTo(0,0); // scrolls the window
```

hard to guess where based on your post, but perhaps

```
$('[name*="RadioGroup1"]').click(function() {  
  $(this).scrollIntoView();
```

Or have a look here: [How do I scroll a row of a table into view (element.scrollintoView) using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1805808/jquery-scrollintoview)

Comment: placed where?  would that be added onto the accordion function? or at the <a href="#"></a>?

Comment: oh, so the scrollIntoView() function will scroll to the name of something, whatever you want to name it?

Comment: sorry for being nebulous.  i needed the second second <a href="#"> to be clicked and bring <blah blah> into focus.

Answer (score 0):

You can bind events to your accordion, either on the object or when you create it.

So change your `$('#accordion').accordion();` to

```
$('#accordion').accordion({
    changestart: function() {
        window.scrollTo(0, 0);
    }
});
```

The `changestart` event will fire every time the accordion changes (on click or what your event for it is).

Comment: that doesn't seem to help.  it doesn't scroll to the top and it breaks the accordion for the sections below the first one.  any insight into why?

Comment: @braveowl : What version are you using? See documentation on UI/Accordion v.1.8 here: http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Accordion

Comment: i'm referencing the google versions online at ajax.googleapis.com