# scrolling to li element - jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have a "ul" that contains lots of "li" (several hundred), the ul has a fixed hight of about 400px and the css property overflow:scroll, each li has the height of 40px so in every given moment there are no more then 10 visible li (the rest need to be scrolled to).
how can i change the scroll position (using jquery) of the ul to a specific li?

any thoughts?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1805808/jquery-scrollintoview

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You need to do something like this:

```
$('#yourUL').scrollTop($('#yourUL li:nth-child(14)').position().top);
```

If you want to animate it, do

```
$('#yourUL').animate({
     scrollTop: $('#yourUL li:nth-child(14)').position().top
}, 'slow');
```

Obviously adjust `14` for different `li`s.

Comment: nice, saved me so much time

Comment: I did that : `$('#yourUL').scrollTop(0).scrollTop($('#yourUL li:nth-child(14)').position().top);` this way we always get position from top.

Comment: you might like this more:
`$('#yourUL').scrollTop($('#yourUL').top + $('#yourUL li:nth-child(14)').position().top);`
since it doesn't involve a weird jump to the top

Comment: Something similar for horizontal scrolling:
`$('#yourUL').scrollLeft($('#yourUL li:nth-child(14)').position().left);`

Answer (score 27):

I got close using @lonesomeday's answer, but I found that I had to calculate the relative position of the specific `li` from the first `li` because it changed depending on the current scroll position of the containing `ul`.

```
$('#yourUL').scrollTop($('#yourUL li:nth-child(14)').position().top - $('#yourUL li:first').position().top)
```

Comment: Perfect - you can also scroll it into position based on the content of the LI 

$('#yourUL').scrollTop($('#yourUL li:contains('+texttofind+')').position().top - $('#yourUL li:first').position().top)

https://jsfiddle.net/cetgk5op/

Answer (score 3):

You can do like this:

```
$('html, body').animate({
     scrollTop:$('#ulID li:eq(1)').offset().top
}, 1000);
```

You need to adjust value to `eq` for specific `li` or you can even customize the selector.

Comment: but isnt this changing the scroll position of the entire body? i want to change the scroll position of the ul

Comment: @Ran: You need to specify appropriate selector in place of `#ulID li:eq(1)` as per your requirements :)

Comment: @Ran: Change `$('html, body')` to `$('#your-UL')`

Comment: @thirtydot That'll give a kooky effect -- it needs `position()` not `offset()` given that we aren't talking about the absolute position of the element here, but that compared to the element.

Comment: @lonesomeday: Didn't really look that hard to be honest. When I wrote that comment, your answer wasn't there yet. I just answered the "isnt this changing the scroll position of the entire body" comment.

Comment: @thirtydot Sorry, I didn't realise it was Sarfraz's post in the first place, rather than yours.

Answer (score 2):

If anyone needs a vanilla JS version, the following is working well for me, the value of 50 is just so that I'm showing the whole item when I'm near the top of the list.  You can adjust that.

```
function updateListSelection(liID) {

    var list = document.getElementById("id Tag Of The <UL> element"),
        targetLi = document.getElementById(liID); // id tag of the <li> element

    list.scrollTop = (targetLi.offsetTop - 50);
};
```