# jquery, how to scroll the selected option into visible view?

Tags: jquery

Here I created a sample to help me be understood,
http://www.jsfiddle.net/BLvsF/

I want the item-'a6' to be scrolled into the visible select box, how can I make it?
I'd like to use jquery to do same as

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#btn').click(function() {
        document.getElementById('a6').scrollIntoView();
        });
});
```

but, how to implement the same using jQuery?

I tried using .get(0).scrollIntoView(). but still not applicable.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#btn').click(function() {
        $('#a> option:selected').clone(false).appendTo('#b').get(0).scrollIntoView();
    });
});
```

http://www.jsfiddle.net/CYQfD/

Thanks,
Elaine

Comment: give the a6 item a `selected="selected"` or isnt it what you want?

Comment: Please provide markup for the users so they dont have to leave this site

Comment: @Luke, copied the markup here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just replace the button handler with this line of code, and you are done.

```
$('#a').val('a6').scrollIntoView();
```

Answer (score 2):

This works fine...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#btn').click(function() {
        //document.getElementById('a6').scrollIntoView();
        var target = $("#b");
        $('#a> option:selected').clone(false).appendTo(target);
        target.get(0).selectedIndex = target.get(0).options.length - 1;

    });
});
```

Comment: a trick :) but changed selectedIndex, can do, I perfered using another way.

Answer (score 2):

My answer is not much more than applying the solution of [How to scroll a select list with JavaScript or jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7205702/how-to-scroll-a-select-list-with-javascript-or-jquery) to your jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/BLvsF/58/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#btn').click(function() {
     var $s = $('#a');
     var optionTop = $s.find('[value="a6"]').offset().top;
     var selectTop = $s.offset().top;
     $s.scrollTop($s.scrollTop() + (optionTop - selectTop));
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that with native option element, since it is not an element like a div.
You will have to create a markup over the select that acts like a dropdown, but is extendable. Im right now mobile so i cannot schow you some examples. But there are jquery plugins that let you make the overlay, that you can control easier

Search for jquery dropdown or something and take one that looks easy enough to work with.

Comment: hey, I got it resolved, using .get(0).scrollIntoView(), much easier than I previously thought. thanks anyway.

Comment: yes, this is only scroll view to the top. I found another link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1805808/jquery-scrollintoview but which is still not applicable in Firefox3.6. so, now, I'm still in researching.