# scroll to contents in jQuery / CSS

Tags: jquery, css, drop-down-menu

I was creating a simple select box in `jQuery`. Everything is fine except its `scrolling`.

I need to set the `UL` height with `overflow`, so that i can have a scrollbar.

Please see the jsfiddle : [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/3Jw7B/5/)

On the jsFiddle you can see that `onKeyDown` ( keyBoard down arrow ) selection will move down.

But after its `height` limit its not automatically scrolling down.

Looks like i am doing something wrong, Please help me.

Thanks.

UPDATE :

> Guys, Please understand that the given example fiddle is just an
>   example only. The Actual one differ.I updated my fiddle.

Comment: `ul` with `option` elements as children? Have you validated your HTML recently?

Comment: add a scroll method when you add or remove classes, I think it'll do the job!

Comment: @ahren ahh please never mind .. that was just an example ..

Comment: Just setting the css class does not tell the browser to scroll down. Look at this example on how to scroll a select. Maybe that will help you out. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7205702/how-to-scroll-a-select-list-with-javascript-or-jquery

Comment: @obivandamme let me check ..

Comment: you're trying to make a syntactically incorrect javascript powered replacement for a select box? I don't mean to be unhelpful but why not just use a select box? Aside from that, there are a few issues with your fiddle, including the fact that your selectors are looking for an `option` *element* rather than a class. This is probably why it appears to do nothing.

Comment: @jammypeach huh .. thats an example only dude .. i updated the fiddle.

Comment: @Red I understand that, however it's all we have to go on. Please consider pasting your real code so we can help solve the problem, otherwise all we can do is fix your example. Don't mean to be unhelpful or rude, I hope you understand :)

Comment: @ja thats cool dude .. actually the problem got solved. Please check obivandamme comment.

Answer (score 0):

Your markup is invalid:

```
<li class="option current">Option 1<li>
```

You not closing `li` properly. Should be:

```
<li class="option current">Option 1</li>
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3Jw7B/6/)

**EDIT** Add this bit of jQuery code to the end of yours:

```
$("#select").animate({
   scrollTop: $(".current").offset().top
}, 100);
```

This should give you an idea.