# Scroll dynamic listview in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-listview

I try to scroll a list made by dynamically.
I've found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7205702/how-to-scroll-a-select-list-with-javascript-or-jquery), but it did not help me.
I guess that this is because my list is a dynamic list.
How can I do? I want to scroll dynamic list on select value.

This is a fiddle with my code: http://goo.gl/Tv7wvj
and this is my code

**HTML**

```
<div class="scroll order">
    <ul></ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.scroll{
    overflow-y: scroll;
    width:150px;
    height:80px;
}
```

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    var html = '';
    for(i=0; i<10; i++){
        if(i==6){
            html += '<li> <label><input type="radio" name="radio" value="li'+i+'" checked="checked" /> 0'+i+' </label> </li>';
            continue;
        }
        html += '<li> <label><input type="radio" name="radio" value="li'+i+'" /> 0'+i+' </label> </li>';
    }
    $('ul').append(html);
});

var $s = $('.scroll');
var optionTop = $s.find('[value="04"]').offset().top;
var selectTop = $s.offset().top;

alert("optionTop : "+optionTop+" / selectTop :  "+selectTop);

$s.scrollTop($s.scrollTop() + (optionTop - selectTop));
```

Comment: how exactly is it going to find value="aaaa" ?????  that doesn't exist on you list --- see this that works  https://jsfiddle.net/nn5fpmqa/

Answer (score 0):

([Question answered in the comments. Converted to a community wiki answer.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments))

@Tasos wrote:

> how exactly is it going to find value="aaaa" ????? that doesn't exist on you list --- see this that works [jsfiddle.net/nn5fpmqa](https://jsfiddle.net/nn5fpmqa/):
>
> ```
> $(document).ready( function() {
>     var html = '';
>     for(i=0; i<10; i++){
>         if(i==6){
>             html += '<li> <label><input type="radio" name="radio" value="li'+i+'" checked="checked" /> 0'+i+' </label> </li>';
>             continue;
>         }
>         html += '<li> <label><input type="radio" name="radio" value="li'+i+'" /> 0'+i+' </label> </li>';
>     }
>     $('ul').append(html);
> });
> setTimeout(function() {
> var $s = $('.scroll');
> var optionTop = $s.find('[value="li6"]').offset().top;
> var selectTop = $s.offset().top;
>
> alert("optionTop : "+optionTop+" / selectTop :  "+selectTop);
>
> $s.scrollTop($s.scrollTop() + (optionTop - selectTop));
>     }, 2000);
> ```