# I have an issue with jquery scrollto

Tags: jquery, html, scrollto

What I'm trying to do: when you select a project from portfolio the page scroll down to show it say 500px down however I seem to be missing something but I'm not sure what? can anybody help?

link: http://www.floodgateone.com/flood/#

```
<a href="#" onclick="$.scrollTo( { top:500, left:0}, 800 ); return false;"">
```

Comment: Dont know if this help, but I was also using scroll.to, and noticed that it seemed to break when I updated my jquery to the latest, from 1.4.2. I had to roll  back my jquery version

Comment: Also, keep in mind that you are gunna get some down votes for requiring that people go over to your site and sift through your source and help you debug it, as opposed to posting some specific examples right here.

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to answer this question as;

1. We don't know what you have and have not tried.
2. You have not posted any code on what you have tried.

However, there is a similar question in SO that might answer your question.  If not then please provide us with some code so we can help better.

[How do I scroll a row of a table into view (element.scrollintoView) using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1805808/how-do-i-scroll-a-row-of-a-table-into-view-element-scrollintoview-using-jquery)