# overflow:hidden but let the content auto-scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, overflow

I have a div where content is appended periodically to it via query's `append()`. As the content gets longer, it will eventually overflow the div. I want no scrollbars to appear when overflowed, but still have the content scroll up to show the new content below.

Is this possible? When I use `overflow-x: hidden` no scrollbar appears but the content is hidden.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the size of the container is fixed, you could place the content inside an absolutely positioned wrap like so:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="wrap">
        <p>bah</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

and css:

```
.container {
    y-overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
}

.wrap {position:absolute; bottom: 0; left:0;right:0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sXGd9/

Answer (score 0):

`append()` will add to content at the end. You may want to `prepend()` new content, so the data get added before the old content.

As for `overflow`, you can set it to `scroll` so that scrollbars appear if necessary, or `hidden` so no scrollbars will appear but the content won't be visible. Otherwise  you can set it to `visible` so it will be visible but the scrollbars won't appear.

Do you want the overflowed content to be visible? If so set the `overflow: visible` otherwise set `overflow: hidden` (because you don't want scrollbars).
Anyway with this you wan't be able to scroll the content. If you need to scroll you have to build your own scroll system, adding event handler to your container.

Answer (score 0):

If you have each appended content in your "#container" div wrapped in a seperate ".append" div you can do something like:

```
var pos = $('#container div:last').position();
$('#container').scrollTop(pos.top);
```

Is this helpfull?

Other solutions can be found in earlier post:
[How do I scroll a row of a table into view (element.scrollintoView) using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1805808/how-do-i-scroll-a-row-of-a-table-into-view-element-scrollintoview-using-jquery)