# How to go to an specific anchor when entering the page (doesn't work)

Tags: javascript, html, anchor, markup

First of all, thats my current state of play: [thsbrk.de](http://thsbrk.de).

The black boxes should be e.g. a about section. I want to achieve that if you enter my page (thsbrk.de) you directly go to my reference section (anchor '#references'). Then, if you hit the about link you will scroll up to that about section. I already tried to make it working but it doesn't. The anchor seems to be not working.

It would be awesome if someone could look at my code and offer me a solution :)

(The scroll isn't implemented yet, I only ask for the anchor problem)

EDIT: Here I've got a example how it should work: [Example](http://volll.com/)

Comment: They scroll. They use window.scrollTo

Answer (score 1):

Give a script tag like this in the head.Let it be the first script also.

```
<script>
location.href="http://thsbrk.de/#references"
</script>
```

From your code, you have did the same. But just try reordering the script tags it might work.

Answer (score 1):

Plain JS:

```
window.onload=function() {
  var anchorHash = 'references';
  document.getElementsByName(anchorHash)[0].scrollIntoView();
}
```

Here is a jQuery example from 2009 - there may be newer ways

[How do I scroll a row of a table into view (element.scrollintoView) using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1805808/how-do-i-scroll-a-row-of-a-table-into-view-element-scrollintoview-using-jquery)

In your case this might work

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var anchorHash = 'references';
  var pos = $('#'+anchorHash).position();
  window.scrollTo(0,pos.top);
});
```

Comment: Since the element in question does not have a `name` attribute set, this will not work.

Comment: I don't want to scroll it in. I will edit an example into my post.

Comment: @Vilx: This is from his site: 
`<div id="cola" class="grid_7">
 <a name="references"></a>`

Comment: Okay cool, thank you, I think I will have a try. I hope it'll work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this and tell me the result:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   window.location.href = '#references';
});
```

and then modify your anchor tag like this:

```
<a name="references">Here</a>
```

Comment: That is a poor solution. why not just scroll or set location.hash?

Comment: Because he/she does not want force the visitors to use the scroll bar.  I think it can't be hard to understand.

Comment: That seems to be almost the same I've had already done, only with the document ready function missing. Will give it a try.

Comment: Don't forget that you need to have enough page height to be able to navigate users to wherever you want. Otherwise, your anchor may not to be at the top of the page.