# jquery container scrolling scrolls page as well in Safari/Chrome

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, safari, scroll

I'm using the code provided by Abhijit Rao on the [following page](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3782959/392591) which brings an element into view when it's contained inside and overflow:auto container.

I'm using this for a custom combobox that I'm creating and it works well in all browsers apart from Safari/Chrome where the items are scrolled into view, but the page also scrolls.

Any idea how to stop them from doing that?

Thanks,
Jacques

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would seem that the JQuery event.preventDefault() works in this case, although I'm not quite sure why it only affected webkit browsers.