# Scroll to top button with jquery accordian

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, scroll, accordion

I have a set of buttons that reveal content using a jquery accordion (for a mobile site).  I am wondering what the best way would be so that when a user selects the other button, it scrolls to the top of that button that was selected.

Here's what I currently have for my accordion script:

```
$( "#accordion" ).accordion({
        collapsible: true,
        active: false, 
        autoHeight: false,
        clearStyle: true
    });
});
```

I also made [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ultraloveninja/6skgc/5/), but it doesn't really function like it does when viewing it on a mobile device (unless you resize the window/viewport area.  Then it functions like it would on a mobile device.)

Answer (score 1):

I found [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1805808/how-do-i-scroll-a-row-of-a-table-into-view-element-scrollintoview-using-jquery).

According to the comment, you could use `element.scrollIntoView()` for the active element, since this *'is supported in all major browsers'*.

There is also a mention to a [jquery plugin](http://erraticdev.blogspot.co.at/2011/02/jquery-scroll-into-view-plugin-with.html) (in the third answer), which does the same thing.

If you bind to the `change` event of the accordion, the following should work:

```
$('#myaccordion').accordion({
  // .. other options
  change: function(event, ui) {
            ui.newHeader.scrollIntoView(); // or scrollintoview(), 
                                           // if you're using the plugin
          }
});
```

I haven't tried either solution, perhaps you could post a comment if one of them works?

**EDIT**

After rereading your question it seemed, that you won't need the `scrollIntoView` function/plugin, since the button you press will usually already be in view (how would you have pressed it...).

So, you might just use `window.scroll` (or whatever scrollable top-level container you use).

Based on your jsfiddle example, the following seems to work:

```
    $( "#accordion" ).accordion({
        collapsible: true,
        active: false, 
        autoHeight: false,
        clearStyle: true,
        change: function(event, ui) {
            if (ui.newHeader) {
            var scrollTop = ui.newHeader.position().top;
            window.scroll(0,scrollTop);
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Hmmm.  Well, I tried adding in the scrollIntoView plugin and that doesn't seem to work. Unless I have it setup wrong.  Here my updated fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/ultraloveninja/6skgc/6/