# html anchor links

Tags: html, anchor

I want there to be anchor links on a webpage where when I click on the link, it brings me to a certain part of the webpage.

However, when the user click the back page button, it is now bringing the user to the previous part of the page, instead of the previous page.

How should I implement the link so that it does bring the user to the previous page instead of the previous part of a page?

```
<a href="#some part">link</a>
```

Comment: Messing with the way history works is usually a bad idea. Users expect things to be consistent.

Comment: is there a way to anchor without doing a href?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I wonder if you could do something like what is described in the top answer of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68165/javascript-to-scroll-long-page-to-div). Put the following into the 'onclick' of your anchor, and it'll scroll to your div of choice, without changing the URL (and hence preserving back-button functionality).

```
document.getElementById('youridhere').scrollIntoView();
```

Don't forget to take out the "href=#somepart".

Comment: don't forget to finish the event handler with event.preventDefault and/or event.stopPropagation

Answer (score 3):

That is how the anchor tags work.  Your best bet is to read here and use it to remove your anchor jumps from browser history.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history