# Jump to generated anchor(id) after success with AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax

Good evening,

this is what I'm trying to achieve: on AJAX 'success' the page has to jump to a generated anchor.

this is the AJAX:

```
    success: function(html){  

// Refresh certain files

$pc("#load_comments").load("core/comments/view_comment.php")
     $pc("#replyid").val('');
     $pc("#replyat").val('Write a comment');
     $pc("#comment").val(''); 

// Jump to anchor function


  }
```

The page has to jump this anchor

```
<a name="lcn_post' .($id). '"></a>
```

Any ideas? I've tried a few ideas but no success yet.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Are you looking for something like [`scrollIntoView`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2368393/317849)?

Comment: I tried: success: function(html){  

// Refresh certain files

$pc("#load_comments").load("core/comments/view_comment.php")
    $pc("#replyid").val('');
    $pc("#replyat").val('Write a comment');
    $pc("#comment").val(''); 
document.getElementById('lcn_post" + id +"').scrollIntoView();
  } but doesn't work, or is the code wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$("[name='lcn_post" + id +"']").focus();
```

it's in jQuery notation.

Comment: have you anything else on the page steeling .focus()? Make sure that you are trying to .focus() on your element after it has been generated.