# how to navigate to another section of the page using javascript?

Tags: javascript

```
<div class = "searchMobile  originalSearchBar">
    <form class = "mobileForm" action="#" onsubmit="return false;">
        <div id="searchExpandTrigger"></div>
        <button type="submit" id="clearSearchMobile" onclick="clearSearch('mobile')"><img src = "img/icon/searchClose.png"/></button>
        <input class="originalInput" type="search" name="search" id="keywordMobile" onkeypress="searchKeyPressMobile(event)" style = "margin-left:25px">
        <button type="submit" id="btnSearchMobile" class="originalButtonPosition" onclick="submitMobile(keywordMobile.value)" /><img src="img/icon/searchIcon.png"/></button>
    </form>
</div>

<div id= "searchResult"></div>
```

What i want is to let the webpage scroll to the #searchResult div tag when the user clicks the submit button (#btnSearchMobile). Is it possible to create this action using Javascript?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/68165/javascript-to-scroll-long-page-to-div

Answer (score 3):

In case you're not using jQuery, you can go with plain vanilla javascript:

```
window.scrollTo(0, document.getElementById('searchResult').offsetTop)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the JQuery scrollTo plugin : https://github.com/flesler/jquery.scrollTo

Demo : http://flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/

Comment: before you have to set and id to the div you want to navigate to

Answer (score 0):

```
 $.scrollTo( '#target-examples', 800, {easing:'elasout'});
```

here '#target-examples' is the section you need to go in that page.

In your example use calling as below

```
$("#btnSearchMobile").click(function(){
 $.scrollTo( ' #searchResult', 800, {easing:'elasout'});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can us the id of the search div and append it to the url.

In your case:

```
document.location += "#searchResult";
```