# Get child margin related to parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How can I find what's the distance between top of the parent div and top of the child div ?

[image]

For example how can I know at what distance (height) div 2 starts related to parent div ? so I can scroll to it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `div.getBoundingClientRect().top` to return the distance from top of the viewport. Just subtract the parent's `getBoundingClientRect().top` from it. ([Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6ew7e/), [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.getBoundingClientRect))

BUT: Since you only need to scroll there, you can use `div.scrollIntoView()` (answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68165/javascript-to-scroll-long-page-to-div), [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.scrollIntoView))

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery to find div2's position:

```
$('.div2').offset();
```

And how much you've already scrolled (if any):

```
var scrolled = $(window).scrollTop();
```

Then just subtract them

```
var distanceFromTop = offset.top - scrolled
```

This gives you the distance between the top of Div2, and the top of the viewport. Now you can tell your script to scroll down by that amount, or not to scroll if you're already past it.

Comment: I marked @bjb568 answer as 'accepted answer' because I didn't specified that I need javascript or jquery and because his answer contain examples, but your answer is good too. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Will this help in any way?

```
function pxToInt(val) {
    return parseInt(val.replace('px', ''));
}

var a = pxToInt($('#parent').attr('padding-top'));
var b = pxToInt($('#div1').attr('margin-top'));
var c = pxToInt($('#div1').innerHeight());
alert(a + b + c);
```

Comment: What? That will get the height of the border-box, but that isn't what OP wanted.

Comment: This gets the top of the second element relatively to the container. Am I missing anything?

Comment: Oh. Wait… misread it. Still, there may be more than just a,b,c. Definitely not a robust solution.