# Semantic elements for footnote list and content

Tags: html

Given a set of footnotes at the end of an article:

```
<article>
    <p>Some content here</p>
    <ol class="footnotes">
        <li id="footnote-1">Footnote 1 text</li>
        <li id="footnote-2">Footnote 2 text</li>
    </ol>
</article>
```

Is there an HTML5 container element more descriptive/semantic than a `ol` or `div` with class = "footnotes" (or is there an appropriate container that should be wrapping the `ol` element)? And, is there a text element more descriptive/semantic than a `p` or `li` for each individual footnote? If not, is there perhaps a microformat out there that at least establishes some common class names to use?

Note this question is not about the markup for footnote *links* - that's [already been discussed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66964/how-do-i-create-a-link-to-a-footnote-in-html) and it appears that there is still no element in HTML to semantically identify a footnote link. I left out the footnote links and back-links from the sample markup here for brevity.

Comment: Since it's not paper, it would definitly add hover texts.

Comment: How about `<footer>` element?

Comment: I thought `footer` was more appropriate for the footer of the entire web page? e.g. I'm using it as a page footer with copyright, etc. What if there are multiple `article`s on a page, each with their own footnotes?

Comment: @Jonathan what do you mean by "add hover texts"?

Comment: Like a tooltip I guess?

Comment: That's what I figured. That's not related to my question at all though.

Comment: @esker - From [the spec](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/sections.html#the-footer-element) "The footer element represents a footer for its nearest ancestor sectioning content or sectioning root element." `Article` elements are sectioning content elements. So each `article` can have its own `footer`

Comment: @Alohci excellent, I did not know that. Why don't you write this as an answer? Though I would like to see if others have different solutions or evidence that there is no better option.

Comment: @esker - Because 'footer` is arguably not the right answer. `footer`s are primarily for metadata about the content of the section, and any given footnote may or may not meet that criterion.

Comment: As of today, there is a footnote tag: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27044589/syntactic-sugar-in-html-xhtml/66450041#66450041

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There isn't any dedicated mechanism yet, but footnotes either with linked, or simple footer notes with list elements as well as side notes can be merged into a common suggested alternative markups. You might have seen this already - ["HTML5 Common Idioms without dedicated elements"](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/common-idioms.html#footnotes)

Sure it's more viable to wrap each footnotes within a `<section>` element if more than one  occurs within a single `<article>`. If that's not the case you can wrap 'em within `<footer>` or `<aside>`. Then content elements follows as usual. Like `<p>` for descriptive segments.

Here is another example of "**[Footnotes with microformats](http://microformats.org/wiki/footnotes-examples)**"