# How to have two different types of footnote references in the same HTML document?

Tags: html, css

I need to have two different types of footnote references on the same HTML text, one with numbers (1,2,3...), the other with letters (a,b,c...).

Ideally, I would have a paragraph in the left column of a two-column table -- this is the main paragraph, i.e. the master text. 
The right column would contain numbered footnotes to certain words of the paragraph in the left column. Just below this, I would have a unified row (with one column) containing a,b,c footnotes to certain words in the main paragraph above.

Is this even possible in HTML? How to implement this?

In case HTML cannot support this, what alternatives do you suggest?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are two links that will be of help to you. Firstly read this previous question in SO which explains how to create hyperlinked footnotes:

[How do I create a link to a footnote in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66964/how-do-i-create-a-link-to-a-footnote-in-html)

Further, if you want to make the reference character superscript or subscript here is an excellent example:

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_sup

So, combined you can do something like this:

```
<p>Some text that has a reference<a id="ref-1" href="#ref-1"><sup>1</sup></a></p>
```

which appears like so:

Some text that has a reference<sup>1</sup>

I hope this is the sort of thing you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks, but what you linked to covers only the general case. What I specifically need to know is: is it possible to mix two footnote systems for the same text (namely numbers and letters)?

Comment: Hello, in short: yes. HTML has no built in footnote scheme, so you can construct it however you wish. The best thing to do is provide a link or example code of your intended page and take it as far as you can until you get stuck, then I can probably give you more specific advice.